# Regex: Match a phrase if NOT preceded by word

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

In JavaScript, I am trying to match all occurrences of the following

```
initChart('something');
initMap('another');

initChart();
initMap();
```

UNLESS it is preceded by the word 'function', meaning, do not match

```
function initChart(param) { ... }
function initMap(param) { ... }
```

Basically I need to strip out all occurrences that invoke the function, while leaving the function definition in tact.  I got this far

```
/init.*(.*)/i
```

This is what my script looks like to strip out matches:

```
var scriptRegex = /init.*(.*)/i;
while (scriptRegex.test(responseHTML)) {
   responseHTML = responseHTML.replace(scriptRegex, "");
}
```

But I'm stuck at how to tell it "only if it is NOT preceded by the word 'function'

Comment: Try using a negate regex like  ^(?!.*function).*$

Comment: @kapricanon: no it's wrong.

Comment: Try `(?<!\bfunction\s)init\w*\([^)]*\)`

Comment: I updated my comment with the language, JavaScript

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I put that in regex101 and it works, but I'm using JavaScript and got `Invalid regular expression`

Comment: I don't believe you can with regexs alone in Javascript, because lookbehinds are not supported ([regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)). You would need a negative lookbehind for this to work.

Comment: @TetraDev: In the original question, there was no code, no mentioning JS. Casimir's approach is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Javascript regex doesn't have the lookbehind feature, so you can't test if there's the "function" keyword before only with regex. *(and most of the time, when this feature is available, the subpattern inside the lookbehind must have a fixed width, this means that you can't test cases where the function name is separated from the "function" keyword with an unknown number of spaces.)*

So you need a workaround. You can for example use capture groups to know if there's a keyword function before with this kind of pattern:

```
/\b(?:(function)\s+)?(init\w*)\s*\(/
```

if the first capture group contains "function" you can exclude the match.

Comment: I see what you're saying. How would I tell my script to exclude the first match, but include the second match? I updated my question with my code that I use to strip out matches.

Comment: @TetraDev; You can't tell anything to your regex. Test the first capture group and if it doesn't contain "function", takes the second capture group. If you need the pattern for a replacement, use a function as replacement to do that.